# Simulating Dynamic Object/Surface Color Interaction in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, mesh, gazebo-model, model

I'm currently working on a project to simulate a robot painting a car part, similar to the process in the video linked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bL07DJk9WQo). I can't find a way to implement the dynamic color interaction between the robot and the car part in Gazebo.

Any suggestions or information related to Gazebo plugins, materials, shaders, or any other relevant tools would be greatly appreciated! If you've worked on a similar project or have insights into Gazebo's capabilities for simulating dynamic color changes, please share your expertise.

Thank you for your help!!